# Google Drive : Publish website

Tags: google-drive-api

I have created a small Html page using AngularJS, twitter bootstrap. 
To test the functionality in different browser and different screens, I wanted to host it on google drive as explained [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en)

I have done the exact steps. But when I try to preview the html page, I get

> web page not available error

.

[My Shared Drive](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxMAc4hNW1tmVjBBbVEya3o5TFk&usp=sharing) which I want to publish